# Hola tengo este problema en un proyecto de next.js. Me salta este error o bug en la consola y no se como solucionarlo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, frontend, next.js

Me dice que necesito un loader adicional para manejar el resultado de los loaders.

Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/loader.js
- ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El error surge en una instalación desde 0 o al hacer un upgrade?